# How to correctly validate an email with regular expressions?

Tags: javascript

I am making a form with regular expression validations. The problem I have is that when I want to validate the email field, I find this series of errors.

The error messages that appear in the box are these in question:

```
Uncaught TypeError: campo is null

validaCampos file:///f:/javascript recuperacion/ejercicioformular/js.js:92

validador file:///f:/javascript recuperacion/ejercicio formulario/js.js:36

file:///f:/javascript recuperacion/ejercicio formulario/js.js:3

onload file:///f:/javascript recuperacion/ejercicio formulario/js.js:3

EventHandlerNonNull* file:///f:/javascript recuperacion/ejercicio formulario/js.js:2
```

What the form in question has to do is validate the data in order to give me the option to send it. If I delete the email field and validate only the other 4, if it lets me send it, the error is only found in that field, although just in case I am going to pass the entire code since, as you can see in the image, it marks several errors in different lines of code

```
   window.onload = function(){
        document.getElementById('btnValidar').onclick = function(){validador()};
    
    }
        var arrayFallos =[];
    
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        
     function validador(){
            
            arrayFallos = []
    
            var campoNombre = document.getElementById('nombre');
            var expNombre = new RegExp('^[A-Z]{1}[A-Za-z áéúíó ñ]{2,14}$');//nombre que comprueba las vocales , que emppiece por mayuscula y que vaya de 2 a 14 caracteres
            validaCampos(expNombre,campoNombre);
           
    
            var campoEdad = document.getElementById('edad');
            var expEdad = new RegExp('^([1][8-9]|[2-5][0-9]|[6][0-5])$');//va desde los 18 hasta los 65
            validaCampos(expEdad, campoEdad);
        
    
            var campoDNI = document.getElementById('DNI');
            var expDNI = new RegExp('^[0-9]{8}[A-Z]{1}$');//valida un DNI español
            validaCampos(expDNI,campoDNI);
    
    
            var campotlf = document.getElementById('tlf');
            var exptlf = new RegExp('^[679]{1}[0-9]{8}$');//valida numeros de telefono movil
            validaCampos(exptlf,campotlf);
    
    
            var campoemail = document.getElementById('email');
            var expemail = new RegExp('^(.+)@(\\S+)$');
            validaCampos(expemail,campoemail);
    
        console.log("Array fallos en el siguiente log");
        console.log(arrayFallos);
    
        if(arrayFallos.length==0){
            alert("Formulario completo puede enviar");
            document.getElementById("Enviar").disabled=false;
            document.getElementById("Enviar").type='submit';
        }else{
            var fallos = "";
            for(var i=0;i<arrayFallos.length;i++){
                fallos += arrayFallos[i].name+"\n"; 
            }
            arrayFallos[0].focus();
            alert("Los campos: \n"+fallos+"\nNo cumplen los requisitos");
        }
function validaCampos(expresion, campo){

    console.log(campo);

    var idcampo = campo.id

    if(expresion.test(campo.value)){
        console.log("Si "+campo , idcampo);
        return true;
    }else{
        console.log("NO "+campo, idcampo, campo.value);
    
        arrayFallos.push(campo);

    switch(idcampo){

        case 'nombre':
            window.alert("Error en el campo "+idcampo+" : \n\n. valor no valido");
        break;
        case 'edad':
            window.alert("Error en el campo "+idcampo+" : \n\n valor no valido");
        break;
        case 'DNI':
            window.alert("Error en el campo "+idcampo+" : \n\n valor no valido");
        break;
        case 'tlf':
            window.alert("Error en el campo "+idcampo+"  \n\n valor no valido");
        break;
        case 'email':
            window.alert("Error en el campo "+idcampo+"  \n\n valor no valido");
        break;

    }
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

For a petition I add the Html

I added the html part

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script type ="text/javascript" src="js.js"></script>
    <title>Ejercicio 2</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form" action= "">
        Nombre: <input type = "text" id = "nombre" name = "nombre"></br></br>
        Edad: <input type = "text" id = "edad" name = "edad"></br></br>
        DNI: <input type="text" id="DNI" name="DNI"></br></br>
        Telefono: <input type="tel" id="tlf" name="tlf"></br></br>
        Email :<input type="email" id="emial" name="email"></br></br>
        
        <input type="button" value="Validar" name="validar" id="btnValidar">
        <input disabled type="button" value="Enviar" id="Enviar"><!-- La propiedad disabled establece o devuelve si un campo de texto está desactivado o no.
            Un elemento deshabilitado es inutilizable y no se puede hacer clic en él. Los elementos deshabilitados generalmente se representan en gris de forma predeterminada en los navegadores.-->
        <input type="reset" value="Borrar datos del formulario" name="btnBorrar" id="borrar">
    </form>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It appears that in one of your calls to `validateCampos` your `campo` argument is `null`/`undefined`. You can temporarily add `console.log(campo)` as the first line in that function and comment out everything else to see when that happens.

Comment: It can be traced back to `compoemail` being `null`, because `.getElementById` can't find your element. Please attach you HTML here too, so we can see what went wrong.

Comment: I added the html @FZs

Comment: Can I suggest to use a specific library for validation ? It will avoid you lot of possible issue in your process. https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator

Comment: @JardonS It has to be all validation with regex

Comment: @ScottMarcus effectively commenting on the entire function and leaving only the console record allows me to validate the form and submit it but it does not detect any faults and I always accept it as good

Comment: @FZs Yeah A certain mistake of mine, sorry, look now to see if it has been uploaded correctly

Comment: "Don't"? In the old days there was an elaborate regex that you could use, listed in the RFC, but we've relaxed the rules for emails to the point where, really, `anything@anythingelse` is already a valid address, with `anything@anythingelse.atleastonedot` covering external email addresses. Modern HTML comes with `<input type="email">` that form validation can automatically tap into: [just use that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation)? Also, stop using XMLHttpRequest, use [the Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Comment: @chemamar "It has to be all validation with regex"... why? Because `validaCampos` expects a regex? ***Regex really isn't the right tool for email validation***. Looking carefully at your code, you could also pass (for instance) `{test:(value)=>isValidEmail(value)}` to `validaCampos` instead of a regex, using a more sensible way of validating in the `isValidEmail` function.

Comment: The root of the issue is that you mistyped `email`, and wrote `emial` instead in the `id` attribute of the e-mail field.

Comment: @Fzs Yes, you were right that was it, to make sure I have done other tests putting it in another way and it works or else the failure was that (I'm an idiot), anyway, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the user @Fzs I discovered that the error was that a simple spelling mistake and also that to correctly validate the

```
<input type="email" id="emial" name="email"></br></br>
```

the correct thing is this

```
<input type="email" id="email" name="email"></br></br>
```

And the correct regex to validate an email is this

> [a-zA-Z0-9_]+([.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+([.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*[.][a-zA-Z]{2,5}